# Operación y un string en un Textbox

Tags: c#, string, textbox, integer

Hola buen día a todos,

Tengo un problema que creo es un tanto pequeño pero no logro formular la operación correctamente.

Estoy trabajando en un aplicativo de control de un almacén y en esta tengo un Texbox que al pasar correctamente por un registro, el contenido de este disminuirá la cantidad en uno hasta llegar a cero y así cambiar de Multiview.

Al tratar de realizar la operación,  no me hace el cambio que debería por un error de formato pero realmente desconozco como podría arreglar esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero que haga sería asi:

El texto actualmente tiene de contenido " 1 articulos"
pero despues de pasar por la operación que disminuye 1 tiene que aparecer como
"0 articulos"
ya con 0 articulos pasa a la multiview...

¿Como podría hacer la resta y tener agregaro el string de "articulos" al mismo tiempo?

Espero me puedan ayudar y si no fuí lo suficientemente claro, podría ser mas especifico si es requerido.

Saludos y buen día.

Answer (score 0):

la manera en la que lo arreglé fué quitando el string para dejar solamente el entero, añadiendo una variable que irá dando un nuevo valor al texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]